# Get number of modified rows within an "after statement" trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am curious if there is a way to find out within an **"after statement"** trigger how many records have been updated by the DML statement. Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER cnt_trg
AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE 
ON table
DECLARE
  v_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN

  v_cnt := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

END;
```

I know one can achieve that with a compound trigger or with the package variables but is there a way to do it within a single after statement trigger?

Comment: The manual says "The value of the SQL%ROWCOUNT attribute refers to the most recently executed SQL statement from PL/SQL. To save an attribute value for later use, assign it to a local variable immediately." i have a feeling it will not set in the trigger context you are using. You need to use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` direcly after the UPDATE query. ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: I've used  %ROWCOUNT  only   to clarify what I actually want, maybe there's another command, that  can be used instead.